# Equivalence of norm on $c_{00}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I find out that norms $||x||_p=(\sum_{i=1}^n|x
_i|^p)^{\frac1p}$ and $||x||_q=(\sum_{i=1}^n|x
_i|^q)^{\frac1q}$ are not equivalence on the finite sequences space $c_{00}$. But I  can't understand why? It looks like $l^p$ norms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should read $||x||_p=(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x
_i|^p)^{\frac1p}$ and  $||x||_q=(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x
_i|^q)^{\frac1q}$ .

Suppose that the norms are equivalent. Hence there are $a,b >0$ such that

$a||x||_p \le ||x||_q \le b||x||_p$ for all $x \in c_{00}$.

With $x_n=(1,1,...,1,0,0,0...)$ ($ n \in \mathbb N$ and the first $0$ is on position $n+1$), we get

$a \cdot n^{1/p} \le n^{1/q} \le b \cdot n^{1/p}$.

WLOG we assume that $p>q$, then $r:=1/q-1/p>0$ and

$a \le n^r \le b$  for all $n \in \mathbb N$, a contradiction !

Answer (score 2):

The underlying space $c_{00}$ is infinite-dimensional. So there is not reason to expect to get equivalent norms.

The $l^p$-norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are all equivalent, however the constants in the estimates depend on $n$, and degenerate for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: This doesn't  look like an answer to the question.